# How can I customize the chevron down

Tags: html, css, time, border

How can I customize the chevron arrow down. Like having a padding on the right side. Its too near in border.

```css
.waiting-list-time {
    select {
        padding: 100px!important;
        border: 1px solid #B5B5B5;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
}
```

```html
<form class="waiting-list-time">
        <label>Earliest Start Time: </label>
        <select class="waiting-list-time">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2" selected>2</option>
        </select>
        <span>:</span>
         <select>
          <option value="1">0</option>
          <option value="2" selected>30</option>
        </select>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the css you have made doesn't work because the structure isn't right.

If you want your code to work how you want, it should look a little bit more like this:

```css
.waiting-list-time select {
        padding: 5px 20px 5px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #B5B5B5;
        border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<form class="waiting-list-time">
        <label>Earliest Start Time: </label>
        <select class="waiting-list-time">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2" selected>2</option>
        </select>
        <span>:</span>
         <select>
          <option value="1">0</option>
          <option value="2" selected>30</option>
        </select>
      </form>
```

Here is a good resource if you want to customize a little bit more the dropdown arrow: https://fabriceleven.com/design/clever-way-to-change-the-drop-down-selector-arrow-icon/

Comment: Hi thanks for this, i forgot to mention im using sass. thats the reason why my structure is like that:) Anyway I already solved this